# Receive all used slugs

Tags: plugins, slug, entry-slug, plugin-sitemap

I want to create a Excel file with all used slugs in my Craft website.
I've searched for a plugin but without succes. I also tried to find a useful table in the Craft database, also without succes.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I already found a solution. I just created a simple query:

```
SELECT content.elementId entryId, title, uri
FROM `craft_content` content
JOIN craft_elements elements ON elements.id = content.elementId
JOIN `craft_entries` entries ON entries.`id` = content.`elementId`
JOIN `craft_elements_i18n` `elements_i18n` ON elements_i18n.elementId = 
elements.id
```